# How can I get Firefox to use the KDE style?

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, kde

There are some problems using Firefox in Kubuntu.

- The menus are ugly and do not use the KDE style.
- The file browser for uploading or opening files is also ugly, and is not the default KDE mini-file-browser.
- The filetype icons are not shown correctly in the Downloads window.
- In the small Downloads window, if I right-click a file and select "Open Containing Folder", nothing happens.

gtk3-engines-oxygen is installed and "oxygen-gtk" is the default GTK style in System Settings > Application Appearance > GTK.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]
Something tells me I am missing something to integrate Firefox into KDE. What can I do to get Flamewolf - ahem Firefox to integrate nicely with KDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the Blue System's PPA for Firefox integration, as recommended straight from MMartin Gräßlin, KWin's main developer. Link: [Firefox KDE integration in Debian Testing](http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2013/12/firefox-kde-integration-in-debian-testing/)

The Launchpad PPA page for Blue Shell's Firefox can be found here: [firefox-kde](https://launchpad.net/~blue-shell/+archive/firefox-kde)

Note that two packages need to be installed: firefox, and firefox-kde-suport

This will lead to a better experience, as shown in the picture from Martin's blog post. The reason this is not installed by default in Kubuntu is that Kubuntu tries to maintain a "pure" KDE experience, and therefore rarely alters upstream packages. And since Firefox is not a KDE application, upstream (KDE) would have no interest in supporting Firefox. This is the best answer for how to handle integration with Firefox + KDE in Kubuntu.

Editorial: If more people file bugs on the matter, maybe it can be addressed. Esp. since Firefox is the default browser now for Kubuntu 14.04, which is a LTS.

Comment: Yes, this is largely a bug in Firefox , as Mr. Gräßlin points out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing when you install KDE Distro is to install gtk3-engines-oxygen.

```
sudo apt-get install gtk3-engines-oxygen
```

Then re-apply gtk settings in System Settings/Application Appearance/GTK

re-select a GTK2 Theme:  oxygen-gtk

re-select a GTK3 Theme:  oxygen-gtk

and click apply...

Then every program include Firefox should appear correctly.

Comment: Apparently gtk3-engines-oxygen was already installed and also selected in GTK themes.
Thank you, though.

Comment: Do you have such problems with other programs? Last time I have installed Kubuntu, gtk3-engines wasn't pre-installed and all my programs had similar problems.

Comment: Yeah, the same thing happens with LibreOffice and a couple other programs like UNetbootin.